# Magnet Wire vs Resistance Wire - What's the difference

Tags: electromagnetism, wire

What's the difference between magnet wire and resistance wire? Which is better for building an electromagnet?

- [Resistance Wire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K183IPK)
- [Magnet Wire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0082CUNVE)

Comment: Vape Supplies is a srange place to buy wire. Quite likely you will find it cheaper from a regular electronic supplier like Digi-Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistance wire will be made of some higher-resistance material than copper and may or may not be insulated, so will have a higher resistance than the same size and length of copper wire.  Resistance wire would normally be used to make a heating element.

Magnet wire is copper, with a thin "enamel" insulation, and is intended for winding coils for an electromagnet.

Comment: Some of the reviews for the resistance wire, stated they were using it for wrapping something in a vaporizer, if the resistance wire is not insulated wouldn't that cause a short?

Comment: I assume that the vaproizer users would take care to prevent short circuits - otherwise they won't get the desired heating.

Comment: Also, the resistance wire withstands 1500°C, while copper melts at 1084°C. But you don't want to use copper at its limit, because it changes its physical properties. E.g. It becomes weak.